# How can i plot 3d projection using python from a text file...?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I am a beginner in the field of python. I am trying to plot a 3d projection from a text file containing multiple tables. The sample of a file is as follows:

```
 old parameters found on file WAVECAR:
 energy-cutoff  :      900.00
 volume of cell :      199.05
  k-point     1 :       0.0000    0.0000            0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -25.6663      2.00000
      2     -25.6144      2.00000
      3     -11.1229      2.00000
      4     -10.9309      2.00000
      5     -10.9048      2.00000
      6     -10.8874      2.00000
      7     -10.7276      2.00000
      8     -10.6629      2.00000
      9      -4.3196      2.00000
     10      -3.7248      2.00000
     11       1.1756      2.00000
     12       1.1796      2.00000
     13       1.6655      2.00000
     14       1.9005      2.00000
     15       1.9115      2.00000
     16       2.3948      1.90818
     17       2.7068      0.60269
     18       3.2113      0.00004
     19       3.9517      0.00000
     20       3.9902      0.00000
     21       4.5536      0.00000

 k-point     2 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.1250
 band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -25.6662      2.00000
      2     -25.6144      2.00000
      3     -11.1228      2.00000
      4     -10.9338      2.00000
      5     -10.9045      2.00000
      6     -10.8880      2.00000
      7     -10.7276      2.00000
      8     -10.6632      2.00000
      9      -4.2799      2.00000
     10      -3.7204      2.00000
     11       0.9818      2.00000
     12       1.0592      2.00000
     13       1.6660      2.00000
     14       1.8142      2.00000
     15       1.8155      2.00000
     16       2.5756      1.31601
     17       2.7520      0.40073
     18       3.3411      0.00000
     19       3.9921      0.00000
     20       4.2573      0.00000
     21       4.6058      0.00000

 k-point     3 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.2500
 band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -25.6662      2.00000
      2     -25.6144      2.00000
      3     -11.1225      2.00000
      4     -10.9406      2.00000
      5     -10.9038      2.00000
      6     -10.8896      2.00000
      7     -10.7277      2.00000
      8     -10.6638      2.00000
      9      -4.1713      2.00000
     10      -3.7204      2.00000
     11       0.6623      2.00000
     12       0.8871      2.00000
     13       1.2141      2.00000
     14       1.6374      2.00000
     15       2.0643      1.99994
     16       2.7959      0.24996
     17       2.8879      0.07166
     18       3.6028      0.00000
     19       4.1048      0.00000
     20       4.7052      0.00000
     21       4.8484      0.00000
   k-point   410 :       0.6250    0.0000    0.5000
   band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -25.6503      2.00000
      2     -25.6304      2.00000
      3     -11.0737      2.00000
      4     -10.9810      2.00000
      5     -10.8498      2.00000
      6     -10.8486      2.00000
      7     -10.7829      2.00000
      8     -10.7454      2.00000
      9      -3.8153      2.00000
     10      -3.7466      2.00000
     11      -0.0226      2.00000
     12       0.3733      2.00000
     13       1.6915      2.00000
     14       1.9180      2.00000
     15       2.0302      1.99998
     16       2.1485      1.99939
     17       3.3140      0.00000
     18       3.5828      0.00000
     19       4.6023      0.00000
     20       5.0997      0.00000
     21       5.1853      0.00000
```

The complete text file has about 729 k_points tables.
Some of them are presented here (k-point 1,k-point 2,k-point 3,k-point 410). Values after k-points like 0.6250,    0.0000,    0.5000 are the value of kx, ky & kz, respectively, as the value on the x-axis, y-axis, z-axis. The column is given in the table named 'band energies' will be reflected as density/colors in the plot. There is no need for column 'occupation' in plotting.

I have been trying for a month but could not create a program that can plot a 3d projection. I tried to convert the given table into NumPy arrays but did not get a satisfactory result. Then I tried to convert this into a data frame using pandas but failed. I used everything I knew.

Comment: to clarify, are you trying to push one particular k-point into a pandas dataframe which consists of 3 columns and it is those 3 columns that are intended to be used for the 3d plot ?   so in total there will be 4 k-plots, so there will be 4 curves in 3d space...  is this understood correctly ?

Comment: Yes sir.... We are plotting a surface plot using kx, ky and kz that are three dimensions on x axis y axis and z axis and rest is band energy column which is to be represented as density/colour in that plot. Kx, ky and kz are the points just after the k points no as you can see a line... In given table like

 k-point     2 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.1250 . These are three points which is to be used as x axis y axis and z axis plot and in columns only band energy is needed

Answer (score 0):

You would need to read the text file into a dataframe (this is a separate question, but quite simple too given the data). This would most easily be done with `pandas.read_csv`.

For the purpose of the question i have created two example dataframes that contain the `k-point` data and now show how to plot them as 3-d lines.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D




k_point_1 = {
    'band no':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19],
    'band energies':[-25,-24,-23,-22,-21,-10,-9,-1,2,3],
    'occupation':[2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]
}


k_point_2 = {
    'band no':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19],
    'band energies':[-25.5,-24.2,-24,-21.5,-20,-7,-4,0.5,2.5,4.5],
    'occupation':[2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(k_point_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(k_point_2)

print(df1)
print(df2)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
sc = ax.plot(df1['band no'], df1['band energies'], df1['occupation'],'r.--')
sc = ax.scatter(df1['band no'], df1['band energies'], df1['occupation'], color='r')

sc = ax.plot(df2['band no'], df2['band energies'], df2['occupation'],'g.--')
sc = ax.scatter(df2['band no'], df2['band energies'], df2['occupation'], color='g')


plt.show()
```

The two example dataframes look like this:

```
   band no  band energies  occupation
0        1            -25           2
1        2            -24           2
2        3            -23           2
3        4            -22           2
4        5            -21           2
5        6            -10           0
6        7             -9           0
7        8             -1           0
8        9              2           0
9       19              3           0


   band no  band energies  occupation
0        1          -25.5           2
1        2          -24.2           2
2        3          -24.0           2
3        4          -21.5           0
4        5          -20.0           0
5        6           -7.0           0
6        7           -4.0           0
7        8            0.5           0
8        9            2.5           0
9       19            4.5           0
```

And the plot looks like this:

[image]

There are many variants of the above (for example adding many lines (`k-points`) with a `for loop` or taking an average and plotting that or other types of plots.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response...    But in plot we are not using  band no. and occupation.We are taking values of a kx, ky and kz which are written in the beginning of every table just after the kpoints. These are the value which to be taken out for plot and after using band energy column only as density/color we have to draw a suface plot.

Comment: okay,  this would be just as easy and in fact easier to read from a file too as one just needs to search for rows that start with `k-point` and strip the values from that.  The plotting would be identical, just with new values & there would be just one curve.